# Java: Cannot print the value of textbox in loop

Tags: java

i have 3 textboxes. One textbox contains the some integer, eg:2 What i want to do is i want to iterate the loop 2 times.. in every iteration i want to print the value in textboxes. I am clearing the textbox before going to the next iteration. After 2 iterations i want to make the textboxes editable false. But the problem is the loop iterates 2 times but the value in textbox is printed only for the 1st iteration. I wrote the following code

```
int i=1;
do
{
System.out.println(ext_people_name.getText());
System.out.println(ext_contact_num.getText());
System.out.println(i);
ext_people_name.setText("");
ext_contact_num.setText("");
i++;
if(i>nop1)
{
ext_people_name.setEditable(false); 
ext_contact_num.setEditable(false); 
break;
}
}while(i<=nop1);
```

The output i get right now is

```
neha
8798
1
2
```

Can anyone tell any alternative to this or please help

Comment: The problem is that you empty the text fields on each iteration, instead of setting their text to display the output. Even if you correct that, it still won't work they way you want it to because the text in the text fields will change too quickly for you to notice both iterations. To solve this problem, you will need to add a pause between the first iteration and the second.

Answer (score 3):

```
I am clearing the textbox before going to the next iteration
```

There, you solved your own problem!

Comment: But i want a blank textbox before going to the next iteration.. what do i do?

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use for loop instead of do/while for your code. Refactor your code like this:

```
for (int i=1; i<=nop1; i++) {
   System.out.println(ext_people_name.getText());
   System.out.println(ext_contact_num.getText());
   System.out.println(i);
   ext_people_name.setText("");
   ext_contact_num.setText("");
};

ext_people_name.setEditable(false); 
ext_contact_num.setEditable(false);
```

Comment: @NehaRaje: My code is **exact** equivalent of your code but just more readable and compact. Why you're getting values printed only once is because you're setting those textboxes to empty string inside the loop. Please work through your logic to change that code inside for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You gave the answer yourself - you CLEAR the textbox before the next iteration.  So, it does not contain a value, so it won't print a value.

What you need to do, is to redesign what you are doing and break it into smaller steps. Instead of trying to use one loop to do everything, break it down into smaller loops.

I also do not quite understand what you want to do precisely. Why is the textboxes cleared before the next iteration?

If you only want to display the textbox values twice, and then clear them and make them uneditable, do that in separate steps.

Alternatively, edit your original question and add some more context that we can understand it better.

Comment: I am clearing the textboxes so that the user can enter the name and contact number 2nd time.

Comment: Why not simply have two name text boxes and two contact number boxes? Is there any reason to do it twice?

Comment: actually i want to generate textboxes dynamically upon no the integer input in the 3rd textbox. I had problem with that. So i tried this way. But here the problem is where to clear the textboxes?

Comment: Do you want to continue asking for information until the user enters nothing any more?

Comment: If the value in the 3rd textbox is 2 i want to ask user to enter the values in the textbox 2 times.

Comment: Wait a second. There's a third text box now?  Might I suggest you edit your original question and explain everything to us, please? I don't think that we (I) fully understand what you want to do. Remember that we don't know everything you know, so kindly take a moment and bring us into the picture as well, then we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are clearing the value in the textbox after each iteration, this make the value empty and prints nothing

```
System.out.println("some   "+ext_people_name.getText()); 
System.out.println("some   "+ext_contact_num.getText());
```

use above code that, you can come across that you are overwirting the result after iteration